# migrating from CodeBlocks 10.5 to 12.11 and got runtime error __static_initialization_and_destruction_0

Tags: c++, codeblocks

i have just upgraded my codeblocks from 10.5 to 12.11 version

everything working fine in previous version, but i got runtime error when compiling with latest version of codeblocks

the call stack pointed my main static class for the problem and show this massage

```
0x0040f9ef in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535)
```

this is code my code

game.hpp

```
...
class Game
{
public:
//... static Member function
private:
    static sf::RenderWindow _mainWindow;
//..... static member variable
};
```

game.cpp

```
... function declaration
sf::RenderWindow Game::_mainWindow; //Runtime Error happen here
//and the other member variable declaration
```

please, tell me where i'm wrong, thanks before

Edit : game.cpp

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sf::RenderWindow Game::_mainWindow;`?

Comment: cris : sory, it's my bad for renaming my class name from original one

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler, I'm pretty sure. It seems you are using GCC as a compiler. What's its version?

Comment: 4.71 i think, i'm use the newest codeblocks 12.11 built in version.